# Radio button value selector

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms, selector

I am trying to write a form. In the form there will be one set of radio buttons. When I open my html page on my browser, I would like to click one of the buttons and then write its value in a text after I click a submit button.

This is part of the form code:

```
<form method="post" action="" id="formToSave">
    <dl>
        <dt>Tipo di booster:</dt>
        <dd><input type="radio" checked="checked" name="tb" value="1"/>
            block
            <input type="radio" name="tb" value="2" />
            dark
            <input type="radio" name="tb" value="3" />
            f1b
            <input type="radio" name="tb" value="0" />
            custom
        <p></p>
    </dl>
</form>
```

And this is part of my javascript code:

```
function buildData(){
var txt =
    "type = " + ($("[name='tb']").is(":checked") ? "block" : 
                ($("[name='tb']").is(":checked") ? "dark" : 
                ($("[name='tb']").is(":checked") ? "f1b" : "custom"))) 
    return txtData;
}

$(function(){
    // This will act when the submit BUTTON is clicked
    $("#formToSave").submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var txtData = buildData();
        window.location.href="data:application/octet-stream;base64,"+Base64.encode(txtData);
    });

});
```

But it is currently not working properly (it won't save the right selection in `txt`).

How can I fix it? Thanks in advance

UPDATE:
From one of the answers:

```
function buildData(){

    var txtData =
            "some text...  " +      $("[name=tipoBooster]").change(function() {
                var txt = ["custom","block","dark","f1b"][this.value];
                console.log(txt);
            })          + "other text...";              
            
    return txtData;
}
```

Comment: I  see no event handler for check changing of the radio buttons?!

Comment: Could you add some more javascript code you are using, this seems incomplete.

Comment: I added some code

Comment: @hellomynameisA would you  like to check my solution?!

Comment: Hi! I am trying it haha... I am trying to understand why here it works perfectly while on my file it returns error or "[object Object]"
Btw, thanks for answering with also a code snippet, it helps a lot :)

Comment: what Jquery version you are using

Comment: This one http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js

Comment: It's older... do you think I should just replace mine with yours? Or do you think a lot of other errors in other parts of the code would occour?

Comment: yes it's very old, replace it with this `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Ok! Done :) Now it never gives error and always returns "[object Object]", which is better than before :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple solution for getting user input when the user changes the checked radio button

```js
$("[name=tb]").change(function() {
  var txt = ["custom","block","dark","f1b"][this.value];
  console.log(txt);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" action="" id="formToSave">
    <dl>
        <dt>Tipo di booster:</dt>
        <dd><input type="radio" checked="checked" name="tb" value="1"/>
            block
            <input type="radio" name="tb" value="2" />
            dark
            <input type="radio" name="tb" value="3" />
            f1b
            <input type="radio" name="tb" value="0" />
            custom
        <p></p>
    </dl>
</form>
```

but in your case you need to edit the build function to be  like this

```
function buildData(){
  return "type = " + ["custom","block","dark","f1b"][$("[name='tb']:checked").val()];
}
```

Or if you want more flexible solution you can add labels to your inputs
like this

```js
$("[name='tb']").change(function() {
  console.log($(this).parent().text().trim());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" action="" id="formToSave">
  <dl>
    <dt>Tipo di booster:</dt>
    <dd>
      <label><input type="radio" name="tb" value="1" checked="checked" />block</label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="tb" value="2" />dark</label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="tb" value="3" />f1b</label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="tb" value="0" />custom</label>
    </dd>
    <p></p>
  </dl>
</form>
```

this was for a change event but your build function should be like this then

```
function buildData() {
  return $("[name='tb']:checked").parent().text().trim();
}
```

**Explanation:**

`$("[name='tb']:checked")` gets the checked radio input element

`.parent()` gets its parent since we need the label to get its text

`.text()` gets the text of the label

`.trim()` removes white space before and after the text

Comment: You are welcome glad I could help, I didn't only understand what you need at the beginning :), happy coding

Answer (score 0):

A `#` in a jQuery selector is for selecting by `id` attribute.

What if you change the selector from `($("#tb").is(":checked")...` to  a [name selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/).

e.g.
`($("input[name*='tb']").is(":checked")`

If you just want to get the selected radio button's text. Could you update the html to be.

```
<form method="post" action="" id="formToSave">
    <dl>
        <dt>Tipo di booster:</dt>
        <dd>
            
              <input id="option1" type="radio" checked="checked" name="tb" value="1"/>
              <label for="option1">block</label>
            ...
        <p></p>
    </dl>
</form>
```

Then your function can just return the selected text

```
function buildData(){
  return "type = " + $("input[name*='tb']").is(":checked").next("label").text(); 
}
```

If you don't want to add labels to the html, then I would try `$("input[name*='tb']").is(":checked").next().text();`

Maybe sharing a minimum working example link would help, as I am just writing the above from memmory, referencing the documentation (https://api.jquery.com/text/#text).

Comment: Hi! I tried your suggestion. It only works for "block", then it gives the wrong answer or error for the other ones... but thanks

Comment: yea. I think there is an issue with the sequential logic. I would wrap your html inputs in label elements and select the text that way. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your selector is referencing an id not the name attribute. Try this instead.

```
var txt =
    "type = " + ($("[name='tb']").is(":checked") ? "block" : 
                ($("[name='tb']").is(":checked") ? "dark" : 
                ($("[name='tb']").is(":checked") ? "f1b" : "custom")))
```

Comment: Thanks, I updated my question... it works better than before, but still has some problems selecting the right radio button :')

Answer (score 0):

You could use: `$("[name='tb']").val()` and just set the corresponding values on the actual radio buttons to `block` `dark` etc.

e.g:

```
<input type="radio" checked="checked" name="tb" value="block"/>
            block
            <input type="radio" name="tb" value="dark" />
            dark
            <input type="radio" name="tb" value="f1b" />
            f1b
            <input type="radio" name="tb" value="custom" />
            custom
```

Comment: It seems interesting! And how can I check which radio button is selected? I am still not very good at jQuery...